# Proper Way to Handle Date Forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, datepicker, mongoid

I wonder what is the proper way to deal with date forms and date field in Rails. I've got a validator in my model:

```
validates_format_of :birthdate, :with => /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/
```

But I still getting this error in my controller when the date is invalid:

```
argument out of range
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You won't match single numbers with that.  Try:

```
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
```